# What are some Apps or add ons that get used to customize Django Admin

Tags: django, admin, markdown

Im looking for a list or just suggestions on some Django Admin must haves or things that people tend to use.

I'm particularly interested in adding a Wysiwyg or Markdown Editor to the the TextAreas in the Django Admin.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of apps that add wysiwyg editors to Django's admin, such as [django-wysiwyg](https://github.com/pydanny/django-wysiwyg.git). There are also a couple of articles on this subject in [Django's wiki](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AddWYSIWYGEditor.). Some other django apps that are great for admin customization are django-admin-tools and [grappelli](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli). Beyond being a general ovehaul of the user interface, grappelli also includes support for the inclusion of a wysiwig editor. And as always, the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.org) are usually a good first stop.

Personanlly, I'm particularly fond of grappelli, it's been used to great effect on a number of Django projects, including [mezzanine](https://mezzanine.jupo.org/) and a few of my own! Here's a preview of the facelift it gives Django's admin:

[image]

Comment: Super! Thats the kind of stuff I needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

Have you take a look at this [list](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AddWYSIWYGEditor) ?

Answer (score 0):

I use the django-adimin-tools myself, it lets you create custom menus and custom dashboard as well as custom css. Here is what it looks like pretty much out of the box. Items are draggable. More on that [here](http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/).

[image: Django Admin Tools Look]

I also used django-admin-bootstrapped which uses twitter bootstrap to make the admin look nicer. more information on it [here](https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped).

[image: Django Bootstrapped Admin Look]

Grapelli is probably the most popular though and I have been using it in my [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) apps but haven't yet tried it in a vanilla Django app as of yet.